# Is this a React bad practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I'm trying to learn some react, so far egghead.io is pretty good, but I have a question. I have the following code:

https://jsfiddle.net/42pe/69z2wepo/49393/

Basically these are 3 sliders which update the state on the parent component. Pretty straightforward.

Specifically, I can update the state like this (by passing both val and color):

```
updateMe(val, color) {
    let obj = {};
    obj[color] = val;
    this.setState(obj);
  }
```

Or I could use the Slider ref to `findDOMNode()` and then get the value to update the state, but that just didn't feel right. I have no clue what React does in the back, but calling a function from an instance, just so that function can find the instance again to get it's value, when the instance itself could be passing it's value (both value and color prop) all along seems weird.

So, is this a bad practice for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are correct but prefer the updateMe . Passing functions in props and child calling that prop function is the ideal way in React.

Refs are ideal where you just want the value and dont want to update state of the react component .For eg , in forms you can use ref to get all the values and make a ajax call to the server.

Answer (score 1):

A better and much cleaner way to do this using ES6 is:

```
updateMe(val, color) {
    this.setState({
        [color]: val
    });
}
```

findDOMNode is not a bad practice. But you do not need use it if, you build your application as a function of state and props. 
Any change to your state or props should change your DOM and any change to your DOM should be as a result of `function of` change in state or props.